# Can't connect to google

Tags: google

I'm using both a 3 year old iMac and a Windows 7 laptop. 80% of the time I am getting an "Invalid URL" error message. Problem exists with IE, Safari, and Chrome. All other sites (yahoo, netflix, amazon, etc) load up perfectly. I can also go directly to gmail.com and access my mail. Problem also with iPad2,iPad mini, and wife's 2 year old iMac. After being unable to get on I will come back a few hours later and be successful.

Comment: Does your internet actually work well? What have you tried to troubleshoot or fix these problems? Can you ping the websites? It sounds to me lke your DNS server isn't working correctly at your ISP, try setting it to Google's DNS (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4)

Comment: Of course, this morning it's all fine. My ISP is Cox Cable. Have been using the service for 10 years. My problem is like having a car that runs perfectly, but stalls when you try to go on a particular road. Thanks for your suggestion. I'll give it a try next time (later today)